# Relatively positioning a widget without Stack in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a widget (Nav Menu) I want to position slightly offset from where it normally falls in my layout.

[image: Holy grail layout showing the nav area moved slightly above where it would normally sit]

When the Nav is expanded, the footer area should get pushed down to accommodate either the Nav area or the Content area, whichever is taller. However, because I am using `Positioned` on my nav menu, it is no longer used to calculate the layout of other widgets on the page. The Nav Menu expands, but is getting clipped to the bounds of the Stack.

[image: Nav menu is expanded and taller than the content area, but the Stack is still the same height, effectively truncating the nav menu to the same height as the content area]

Is it possible to have a positioned widget in a stack which will influence the layout of other widgets? Perhaps there is a way to make the stack grow in height to encompass its positioned children? This probably wouldn't be my desired outcome since I want the part of nav extending into the header to overlap. Is this behavior remotely possible without me writing my own RenderBox?

#### This is what I want

[image: Ideal result showing a tall expanded nav area pushing the footer down below the content and nav widgets]

P.S. When I position my nav menu outside the bounds of my Stack, gesture detection no longer works, which also quite the annoyance.

Comment: I asked the same question yesterday, no answers, but after search I foud widgets that may help, but I don't know how to use them correctly, OverflowBox and UnConstrainedBox widget

Comment: You can probably use one of these? https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Overlay-class.html

Comment: I haven't seen `UnconstrainedBox` or the `CompositedTransformTarget` before. I don't think they apply to the layout I am hoping to achieve, but would happily be proven wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`Stack` won't work because you cannot position widgets relative to each other, only relative to the container. Also, once a widget has been positioned, it will no longer affect non-positioned widgets.

My only recourse seems to be the `CustomMultiChildLayout` widget and its delegate. Now, this comes close, but is not exactly what I need. It adjusts the layout appropriately as I change the size of the window (because of `shouldLayout()` override), however if one of my child components (nav in my prior example) change size, the layout does not recalculate.

The `MultiChildLayoutDelegate` has a `Listenable?` parameter in its constructor, which I should be able to attach to *something* to react to an animation or size change in my children. I'm just not sure what to attach it to. And if I had an expanding panel in both my content child and nav child, can I attach *both* events to this listener?

More to figure out there.

Here is the code for my layout delegate to see how I did it.

```dart
enum LayoutParts {nav, header, content, footer}

class _LargeFormatWizardDelegate extends MultiChildLayoutDelegate {
  _LargeFormatWizardDelegate(this.size);

  final Size size;
  final navWidth = 360.0;
  final maxContentWidth = 792.0;

  @override
  void performLayout(Size size) {
    var headerSize = Size.zero;
    var stepperSize = Size.zero;
    var contentSize = Size.zero;

    if (hasChild(LayoutParts.header)) {
      headerSize =
          layoutChild(LayoutParts.header, BoxConstraints(maxWidth: size.width));
    }

    if (hasChild(LayoutParts.nav)) {
      stepperSize = layoutChild(
        LayoutParts.nav,
        BoxConstraints(maxWidth: navWidth),
      );
    }

    // Need to know the maximum width of the content area which is 100% and
    // capped at 792
    final double contentWidth =
    min(size.width - stepperSize.width, maxContentWidth);

    if (hasChild(LayoutParts.content)) {
      contentSize = layoutChild(
        LayoutParts.content,
        BoxConstraints(maxWidth: contentWidth),
      );
    }

    if (hasChild(LayoutParts.footer)) {
      layoutChild(LayoutParts.footer, BoxConstraints(maxWidth: size.width));
    }

    if (hasChild(LayoutParts.header)) {
      positionChild(LayoutParts.header, Offset.zero);
    }
    if (hasChild(LayoutParts.content)) {
      positionChild(
        LayoutParts.content,
        Offset(stepperSize.width, headerSize.height),
      );
    }
    if (hasChild(LayoutParts.footer)) {
      final controlPosition = Offset(
        0,
        max(headerSize.height + contentSize.height, stepperSize.height),
      );
      positionChild(LayoutParts.footer, controlPosition);
    }
    if (hasChild(LayoutParts.nav)) {
      positionChild(LayoutParts.nav, Offset.zero);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRelayout(_LargeFormatWizardDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate.size != size;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also frustrated with the limitations of `CustomMultiChildLayout`, which was the original inspiration for creating the [Boxy](https://pub.dev/packages/boxy) package.

The following implementation allows the nav menu and content to size themselves, ensures the part of the menu overlapping the header can be hit tested, and sizes itself to the tallest child:

[image]

[image]

```dart
class NavMenuScaffold extends StatelessWidget {
  const NavMenuScaffold({
    Key? key,
    required this.header,
    required this.navMenu,
    required this.navMenuInset,
    required this.content,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Widget header;
  final Widget navMenu;
  final double navMenuInset;
  final Widget content;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomBoxy(
      delegate: NavMenuScaffoldDelegate(
        navMenuInset: navMenuInset,
      ),
      children: [
        header,
        navMenu,
        content,
      ],
    );
  }
}

class NavMenuScaffoldDelegate extends BoxyDelegate {
  NavMenuScaffoldDelegate({
    required this.navMenuInset,
  });

  final double navMenuInset;

  @override
  Size layout() {
    final header = getChild(0);
    final navMenu = getChild(1);
    final content = getChild(2);

    final width = constraints.maxWidth;

    // Lay out the (green) header.
    final headerSize = header.layout(
      BoxConstraints(
        minWidth: width,
        maxWidth: width,
        // The header needs to be at least this tall in order for the nav menu
        // to accept hit tests.
        minHeight: navMenuInset,
      ),
    );

    // Lay out the (red) nav menu.
    final navMenuSize = navMenu.layout(
      BoxConstraints(maxWidth: width),
    );

    // Position it below the header size, minus the provided inset.
    navMenu.position(Offset(0, headerSize.height - navMenuInset));

    // Lay out the (blue) content, constrain it to the remaining width minus
    // the width of the nav menu.
    final contentSize = content.layout(
      BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: width - navMenuSize.width),
    );

    // Position it to the right of the nav menu and below the header.
    content.position(
      Offset(
        navMenuSize.width,
        headerSize.height,
      ),
    );

    // Calculate the resulting size by taking the header size and adding the
    // maximum height of nav menu / content.
    return Size(
      width,
      headerSize.height +
          max(
            navMenuSize.height - navMenuInset,
            contentSize.height,
          ),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRelayout(NavMenuScaffoldDelegate oldDelegate) =>
      oldDelegate.navMenuInset != navMenuInset;
}
```

The full interactive example can be found at https://dartpad.boxy.wiki/?id=3f1be9838abfee469efb34233e5dadbc